# setAttribute also also setting the value for the following element

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm pretty sure this one is silly but I can't seem to figure it out myself.

This is a Django website containing a little bit of Javascript.

In my HTML, I have a button that should send a few values to a Javascript function. The javascript function should then find and update some divs in the HTML.

The strange thing is that the value assigned to the setAttribute statement is automatically also used for the following innerHTML statement (overruling whatever was configured there).

HTML Button:

```
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="monthStats(
                {{simple_total_monthly_sent_volume}},
                {{average_monthly_delivery_rate}},
                {{average_monthly_unique_open_rate}},
                {{total_monthly_unique_open_volume}},
                {{average_monthly_unique_click_rate}},
                {{average_monthly_rejection_rate}},
                )">Month</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function monthStats (sentvolume,
                    deliveryrate,
                    uniqueopenrate,
                    uniqueopenvolume,
                    uniqueclickrate,
                    rejectionrate
                    ) {
    document.getElementById("sent").innerHTML = (sentvolume).toLocaleString("en-US");
    document.getElementById("delivered").innerHTML = deliveryrate+"%";
    document.getElementById("uniqueopened").innerHTML = uniqueopenrate+"%";
    document.getElementById("uniqueopened").setAttribute("title", uniqueopenvolume.toString());
    document.getElementById("uniqueclicked").innerHTML = uniqueclickrate+"%";
    document.getElementById("rejected").innerHTML = rejectionrate+"%";
}
```

HTML divs that should get updated:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div id="sent" class="keymetric">{{simple_total_monthly_sent_volume|intcomma}}</div><div class="text-muted keymetricexplanation">sent volume</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div id="delivered" class="keymetric">{{average_monthly_delivery_rate}}%</div><div class="text-muted keymetricexplanation">delivery rate</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div id="uniqueopened" class="keymetric" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="{{total_monthly_unique_open_volume|intcomma}}">{{average_monthly_unique_open_rate}}%</div><div class="text-muted keymetricexplanation">unique open rate</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div id="uniqueclicked" class="keymetric">{{average_monthly_unique_click_rate}}%</div><div class="text-muted keymetricexplanation">unique click rate</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div id="rejected" class="keymetric">{{average_monthly_rejection_rate}}%</div><div class="text-muted keymetricexplanation">rejection rate</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clicking on the Month button in the HTML results in the title and textvalue of the div with ID "uniqueopened" to be updated correctly by the Javascript. However, the setAttribute statement in the javascript is seemingly also updating the value of the following div with ID "uniqueclicked", overruling the Javascript statement targeting that div.

Comment: There's nothing that looks wrong with your variable naming, are you sure your values are different? There's no way that setattribute is changing the innerhtml of another element unless the numbers are the same or the names are wrong. On a related note, I think you would be better served by Django's `json_script` filter rather than entering template variables to a function.

Comment: Gosh I tried check that by simply putting {{total_monthly_unique_open_volume}} directly in the HTML. It did show me a number but I'll give that json_script a try anyway - wasn't aware it even existed so at the very least thank you for teaching me something new :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what caused the original problem. But could solve my issue by using an alternative approach: instead of pushing all the values to one single javascript function, I created a separate javascript function that does only the setAttribute updates.